# Where does ... lead to in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I was in `/var/www` folder on my Linux system (Ubuntu 16.04). I moved a folder called "home" into "`...`" via the move command:

```
mv home ...
```

I didn't mean "...", I meant "..", but it was just a typo.

The question now is where is my folder? I couldn't find it anywhere. It's not in the parent folder, nor the upper one, nor anywhere else.

Comment: downvote for using the wrong site; stackoverflow is for programming questions, not linux command-line usage.  Try  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) (not folder - on Linux folders are only a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) artefact) has been *renamed* as `...` (a file name of three dots). Since that name is starting with a dot, it is *conventionally* "hidden".

<sup>Hiding file names starting with a dot is a shell convention, also followed by `ls`, etc...</sup>

Use `stat ...` and `ls -lad ...` to list it (and `ls -la ...` to list that directory's content).

Use `mv -vi ... ../newdir` to move it as the `newdir` entry in the parent directory.

Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

An entry in a directory (that is a "file name", but don't forget that files are [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)s and can have several [file paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) pointing to the same inode, or even none) can have any character except `/` and the NUL byte. You could even have a directory named with a single return character, but that is disgusting.

My recommendation is to use only letters, digits, underscores, dots in file names. Avoid using several dots, avoid using spaces in them (even if you could). Prefer underscore `_` to space in file paths.

BTW, you should not have a `/var/home/` directory, if you want to respect [FHS](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/fhs) conventions (which you should respect, for readability).

Answer (score 3):

Your folder is now called `...`, which means it has a name that starts with a dot and is therefore (by convention) hidden. Look in /var/www with `ls -a` (short for `--all`), which also shows hidden files.